# Phrase can contain two words (or none) and ends in semicolon

Tags: regex, match

I've been looking for a bit on Google and haven't been able to find this specific case of regex. And I think it isn't trivial.

The logical expression is something like this:

```
( (contains #HOUR# AND contains #DATE#)
  OR (not contains #HOUR# and not contains #DATE#) )
AND (ends in semicolon)
```

The phrase in question should always end in `;`, but can have any number of punctuation marks anywhere in the phrase.

It can also contain either two reserved words (delimited with `#` or any special character, eg: `#HOUR#` and `#DATE#`), or none. This means that if there is one word, the other should be also present in the phrase in any order.

For example:

```
asdasdadadasd           -> shouldn't work
asdasdasdaasdasdasda;   -> should work
sdasdadas#DATE#-#HOUR#; -> should work
DATE-HOUR;              -> should work
sdasdadas#HOUR##DATE#;  -> should work
sdasdadas#DATE;         -> should work
```

This is as far as I've gone `^(^.+?\;$)|((?=.*\b#HOUR#\b)(?=.*\b#DATE#\b)).*`.

But that expression doesn't quite work.

Comment: Why shouldn't `DATE-HOUR;` and `sdasdadas#DATE;` work? They both contain neither `#HOUR#` nor `#DATE#`

Comment: It sounds like maybe you can't have DATE or HOUR unless they have "#" on both sides? So maybe `((?<!DATE)(?<!HOUR)|(?<=#DATE#)(?<=#HOUR#));$` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/jI4cI2)):

```
^(?:(?=.*#HOUR#)(?=.*#DATE#)|(?!.*#HOUR#)(?!.*#DATE#)).*;$
```

**Explanation**

```
^(?: (?= .*#HOUR# ) (?= .*#DATE# )   # either contains both '#HOUR#' and '#DATE#'
  |  (?! .*#HOUR# ) (?! .*#DATE# ) ) # or neither of them
.*;$                                 # match everything until the ending ';'
```

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake on my part. For some reason I thought it shouldn't have worked.